# Tkinter - Grid positioning completely unresponsive for some widjets

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code (some code cut out):

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PyCipher")
root.iconbitmap('D:\\PyCipher\\media\\icon.ico')
root.geometry('510x325')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(20, weight=1)
rootframe = tk.Frame(root)
rootframe.grid(row=10, column=5)

headertxt = tk.Label(root, text='PyCipher', font=('Helvecta', 20, 'bold'), anchor='c')
headertxt.grid(row=3, column=5)

entrybox = tk.Entry(root, width=60)
entrybox.grid(row=7, column=5)

entrylabel = tk.Label(root, text='Enter Text to convert')
entrylabel.grid(row=9, column=5)

output = tkst.ScrolledText(master=rootframe,wrap=tk.WORD, width=50, height=10)
output.grid(row=10, column=8)

outputlabel = tk.Label(root, text='Output text')
outputlabel.grid(row=15, column=5)

encodebtn = tk.Button(root, text='Encode', fg='green', command=encode, width=5)
encodebtn.grid(row=7, column=4)

decodebtn = tk.Button(root, text='Decode', fg='orange', command=decode, width=5)
decodebtn.grid(row=7, column=6)

copybtn = tk.Button(root, text='Copy', fg='blue', command=copy, width=5)
copybtn.grid(row=17, column=5)

clrbtn = tk.Button(root, text='Clear', fg='red', command=clear, width=5)
clrbtn.grid(row=18, column=5)


root.mainloop()
```

The issue is with the buttons. When I try to change the column value to 2-4 or 6-9, the elements are completely unresponsive to the position change. But when I set it to column 5, it completely breaks the ui by entering another widjet. Why cant I move any elements in those other columns yet column 5 completely moves the element to the area it should be? Padding ends up padding the entire UI, and even when the elements are far away from others, It still has the same issue.

Comment: Please make the code runnable. You reference functions that don't exist and modules that you haven't imported, and include a reference to an image that is irrelevant.

Comment: When you say "the buttons", do you mean _all_ the buttons, or just the encode/decode buttons, or just the copy/clear buttons? Also, why do you use such sparse columns? It looks like you have at most three columns, yet you have things in columns 4, 5, 6, and 8. Why not use columns 1,2 and 3? The same goes for rows: why not use rows 1,2,3,4,5 and 6? Are you aware that empty rows and columns have a size of zero?

Comment: There was a lapse in my judgement on the column and row config, I thought 10 and 20 were the amount of rows I was configuring. The buttons meant all of the buttons in my progam.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of the grid layout manager are that it will compress the layout to the maximum size of any widget in a row or column. So the columns 1, 2 and 3 will have  zero width, as these contain no widgets. If you move the widget in column 4 to one of these columns, that will not make a difference to the visible state of your layout. Column 4 will now have zero width and its space will be taken up by the column you moved the widget to. As to your statement ' Padding ends up padding the entire UI', I do not understand what you mean here, can't help you there.

Comment: When I use padx to pad it out of a corner, it pads the entire program the the amount of pixels I set.

Comment: Use padx on what? Code please.

Answer (score 0):

look at `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method).

I seem to recall having a similar problem a while ago. You need to give each column/row a weight.

Comment: I did, is 1 not enough?

Comment: so you did! Sorry about that - only col 10 and row 20 have a weight though?

Comment: oh, so I need to do 30 configures just to give everything a weight? tkinter is annoying.

Comment: you could use a for loop with a range? try it and report back

Comment: Also "root frame" will need grid weight

Comment: what is that? root.frame?

Comment: you define rootframe on line 8

Comment: I define a icon on line 8. Also I changed the weight fro everything and nothing is working.